# ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery__(...).tagsinput is not a function

Tags: angular

How to solve above error in angular-cli project

And i am using bootstrap tags input ui

my angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  "assets/plugins/tags_input/bootstrap-tagsinput.css",
  "styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js",
  "../src/assets/plugins/tags_input/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"
]
```

app.controller.ts file

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

ngAfterViewInit() {

$('.tagsinput').tagsinput({
            tagClass: 'label label-primary'
        });
}
```

app.controller.html

```
<input class="tagsinput form-control" type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo"/>
```

i am facing this error

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery__(...).tagsinput is not a function
at advisorCreateEditComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/advisor/advisor-create-edit.component.ts.advisorCreateEditComponent.ngAfterViewInit (main.bundle.js:104)
at callProviderLifecycles (vendor.bundle.js:169756)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (vendor.bundle.js:169727)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (vendor.bundle.js:169711)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:170839)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:171179)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:171137)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:170832)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:171179)
at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:171111)
```

Comment: Did you rebuild your project after adding the scripts?

Comment: once again i rebuild the project. This time also i get same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller.ts file jsut change

```
declare var $: any;
```